# ¿Por que se cierra la session en laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Tengo un problema con el uso de sessiones en laravel.

En `Session.php` en `lifetime` puse para que la session durara 24 horas y funcionaba bien, lo que pasa es que añadí dos `div` para que se actualicen cada segundo y ahora en cualquier momento la session me bota y no dura las 24 horas.

```
'lifetime' => 1440, // 24 horas 
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Codigo JS que añadí.

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('#div1').load('{{route('div1')}}');
   $('#div2').load('{{route('div2')}}');
},1000);
```

Este codigo se ejecuta en todas mis páginas, los 2 `div` pertenecen a una barra nav.
¿Alguna solución?

Comment: "¿Creen que eso esté afectando?", ¿has intentado quitando eso y probando de nuevo?

Comment: Preguntada editada.

Comment: ¿Que pretendes cargar con ese codigo?

Comment: Solo son dos consultas: `$nuevos = Noticia::all();` y `$contador = Noticia::all()->count();`

Comment: ¿En `$('#div1')` presentes insertar la consulta que hace `'{{route('div1')}}'`.?

Comment: ¿Y si suplantas esa manera de cargar por un .append?